# Returning preferences

Tags: scala, authorization

I have a function that returns some preferences, but first I have to do some checks to see whether the user is authorised to read them. I'm still not happy with the result (the match is a bit ugly).

Note: `Result` is a framework class, it just means some kind of response.

```
// implementations are not relevant.
def canAccessPreferences(id: Long): Future[Boolean] = ???
def doGetPreferences(id: Long): Future[Result] = ???

def getPreferences(id: Long) = Future[Result] {

  canAccessPreferences(id).flatMap {
     case false =>
       Future.successful(Forbidden)
     case true =>
       doGetPreferences(id)
  }
}
```

Comment: Curious that you are going to some effort of abstraction with futures and framework classes but have hard coded your **id** everywhere as **Long**.  Such an important type should have a type alias.

Answer (score 2):

The only alternative is using a `for` comprehension:

```
for {
  hasAccess <- canAccessPreferences(id)
  result <- if (hasAccess)
    Future.successful(Forbidden)
  else
    doGetPreferences(id)

} yield result
```

Unfortunately you cannot use the `if` guard of the `for` because then you would get an exception if `hasAccess` is false. And since you're composing `Future` monads there's no way around the `Future.successful` either.